# Mongoose Merge Arrays with FindAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to append an array to an existing array in mongoose via `Schema.findByIdAndUpdate(...)`. It should look something like this:

```
Schema.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $merge: { existingArray: otherArray } }, (...))
```

**Example**

If I have a doc in the database that looks like this:

```
{
    ids: [1,2,3,4]
    ...
}
```

and I want to update this document to look like this:

```
{
    ids: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    ...
}
```

with the help of this array:

```
[5,6,7,8]
```

Is there any suitable operator for my intent?

Comment: Could you explain your question more

Comment: I've added an example, hope this helps :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [**`$push`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator with [**`$each`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#up._S_each) modifier.

Something like this

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "_id" : id },
  { "$push": { "ids": { "$each": [5,6,7,8] }}}
)
```

Comment: Is update right now? mongoose my version is 5.10.3 using findOneAndUpdate. nested array obecjt inside array object need to push do you have any idea ?